# How to match brackets with regex in ruby

Tags: ruby, regex

I am currently trying to create a regex that will find this pattern `/- - [/`.  However, since the `[` is a special character, I am getting this error:

```
premature end of char-class: /- - [/ (SyntaxError)
```

I know this is happening because the compiler is expecting the `[` in the regex to close, but I need it to match that in my pattern.  How can I do this?

Comment: Escape it with a "\": `\[`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, brackets are part of regex syntax. If you want to match a literal bracket (or any other special symbol, for that matter), escape with a backslash.

```
'foo[bar]' =~ /\[/ # => 3
```

Comment: Worked perfectly, thanks!  Regex are still very new to me and by far one of the most confusing things I've encountered

Comment: You should accept the answer as solved if this resolved the issue.